# appropriate mapping a string field length (mapping by code)

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

How can I mapping a string field length to the nvarchar(max) in sql
server?

```
Property<string>(x => x.Content, x => x.Length(Int32.MaxValue));
```

It results in mapping to nvarchar(255) only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Property(x => x.Content, x => x.Type(NHibernateUtil.StringClob))
```

Comment: Just to put my two cents here I leave another way to specify the length

public class MyObjectMapper : ClassMapping<MyObject>
    {
        public  MyObjectMapper()
        {
            Id(x => x.MyObjectId, mapper => 
                                               mapper.Generator(Generators.GuidComb));
             Property(x => x.Descripcion, mapper => mapper.Length(600));
                
        }
    }